# Bash redirections

Tags: bash, sh

Could someone please explain the following behavior of bash and if my understanding is correct:

1. `echo abcd > abc def`

   > the echo abcd prints it out to std out stream, but since due to  the presence of ">" it is redirected to the file abc
   >   How is def stored as a string in the file abc and not as another file containing the string abcd?
2. `echo abcd > abc > def`

   > This results in the string abcd to be stored in the file def and the file abc remains empty. How ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this command:

```
echo abcd > abc def foo bar
```

Only argument after `>` is used for output filename and rest is used for `echo`. Hence you get:

```
cat abc
abcd def foo bar
```

Then in this command:

```
echo abcd > abc > def > xyz
```

Only the last filename after `>` will actually the output content and remaining ones will be empty:

```
cat xyz
abcd
cat def
cat abc
```

To store output in multiple output files use `tee` like this (with suppressed stdout):

```
date | tee abc def xyz > /dev/null
```

Then check content:

```
cat abc
Mon Dec  7 07:34:01 EST 2015
cat def
Mon Dec  7 07:34:01 EST 2015
cat xyz
Mon Dec  7 07:34:01 EST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo abcd > abc def
```

You can place redirection anywhere. The above is the same as `echo abcd def >abc`.

```
echo abcd > abc > def
```

Here, redirection `>abc` is overridden by redirection `>def`. Content of file `abc` is empty because the final redirection that is in effect is `>def`.